# Edit annotation text with an UIAlertViewStylePlainTextInput

Tags: ios, uialertview, mkannotation, mkannotationview

I can drop pin annotations onto a map which has a disclosure button. When that button is clicked an alertView pops up in which I can remove the selected annotation. I am now trying the edit the selected annotation subtitle with UIAlertViewStylePlainTextInput. Any ideas on how I can do this?

```
- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView annotationView:(MKAnnotationView *)view calloutAccessoryControlTapped:(UIControl *)control
{
    NSLog(@"Annotation button clicked");
    UIAlertView * alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Annotation" message:@"Edit Subtitle" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Hide" otherButtonTitles:@"Update Subtitle", @"Remove Pin",nil];
    alert.alertViewStyle = UIAlertViewStylePlainTextInput;
    [alert show];
}

- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex{
    if (buttonIndex == 0) {
        NSLog(@"Hide button clicked");
    }
    if (buttonIndex == 1) {
        NSLog(@"Update button clicked");
        //e.g. subtitle.text = [[alertView textFieldAtIndex:0] text];
    }
    if (buttonIndex == 2) {
        NSLog(@"Remove button clicked");
        [self.map removeAnnotations:self.map.selectedAnnotations];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just like when removing the annotation, you can use the map view's `selectedAnnotations` property to get access to the selected annotation to update its `subtitle`.

The following example assumes you're using the annotation class `MKPointAnnotation` (which has a settable `subtitle` property) for your annotations but you can replace it with your class as needed:

```
NSLog(@"Update button clicked");

//e.g. subtitle.text = [[alertView textFieldAtIndex:0] text];

//Make sure there is a selected annotation...
if (self.map.selectedAnnotations.count > 0)
{
    //Since only one annotation can be selected at a time,
    //the selected annotation is the one at index 0...
    id<MKAnnotation> ann = [self.map.selectedAnnotations objectAtIndex:0];

    //Make sure the selected annotation is one of our types...
    if ([ann isKindOfClass:[MKPointAnnotation class]])
    {
        MKPointAnnotation *pa = (MKPointAnnotation *)ann;
        pa.subtitle = [[alertView textFieldAtIndex:0] text];
    }
}
```

Comment: That works perfectly, replaced `if ([ann isKindOfClass:[MKPointAnnotation class]])` with my annotation `if ([ann isKindOfClass:[MapAnnotation class]])`. Thanks for the help Anna.